# Program crashes on a specific value when i try to free() the arrays in a pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, crash, realloc

im trying to use a dynamic array to calculate average with credits but my program crashes when i run with the values:

- 2 1 1 1 1 3 1 1

it doesn't crash if i do:

- 2 1 1 1 1 4 1 1 1 1

if i remove the for loop with the free(); inside

```
for (i=0 ; i<classes ; i++) 
{   //free each individual 2unit array first
    free(grades[i]);    //This line doesnt work
}
```

it runs fine but i don't want to do that because im told not to do that.

here's the code, i tried to remove the unnecessary parts as best as i can

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void fillArray(int **grades,int start,int finish)
{   
    int i;
    for(i=start;i<finish;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter grade for Class %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&grades[i][0]);
        printf("Enter Credit for Class %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&grades[i][1]);

    }
}
void expandArray(int **grades,int oldSize,int newSize)
{
    *grades = (int *)realloc(*grades,newSize*sizeof(int*));    //expanding the pointer array
    int i;
    for(i=oldSize;i<newSize;i++)   //filling it with 2 unit arrays per class
    {
        grades[i] = (int *)malloc(2*sizeof(int));   
    }
    fillArray(grades,oldSize,newSize);  
}

int main()
{
    int classes,oldClasses;
    printf("Enter number of classes: ");
    scanf("%d",&classes);

    int **grades = (int **)malloc(classes*sizeof(int*));   //creating an array to store 2unit arrays(pointer array)
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<classes;i++)   //filling the pointer array with 2 unit arrays per class
    {
        grades[i] = (int *)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    }

    printf("Enter grades for each classes: \n");
    fillArray(grades,0,classes);    // this 0 here means we start at the index 0, that parameter is later used to start at the lastIndex+1


    oldClasses = classes;   // copied the value of classes to oldClasses instead of taking the new one as newClasses to avoid confusion.
    printf("Enter new number of classes: ");
    scanf("%d",&classes);
    expandArray(grades,oldClasses,classes);
    printf("This line works!");
    for (i=0 ; i<classes ; i++) 
    {   //free each individual 2unit array first
        free(grades[i]);    //This line doesnt work
    }
    printf("This won't get printed with the value 3...");
    free(grades);   //free the pointer array (This one also works)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't cast the return value of `malloc()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/3488231

Comment: i removed the casts on all the 'malloc()' s , i also tried removing the cast on 'realloc()' .But i still get the crash

Comment: Just saying that it's not something you should do. Not saying that it's the cause of your crash. Otherwise I would have posted it as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: oh ok, the reason i was casting is because i was told my code would be incompatible with the old standarts if i didn't. thanks for the info though,i will try removing the cast if i run into problems in the future

Comment: The gave you the wrong hint then, in C `void*` has always converted to any data pointer type. The only context where this poses problems is C++, but you shouldn't use `malloc` there, anyhow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`expandArray` is actually updating `grades` which is an `int**` but inside you are updating `*grades`: You are expanding the **first** array from **2** grades to **`newSize`** grades while you wanted to add a new entire class.

You want to pass the **address** of the object you want to modify in the function, so you should pass a `int***`.

```
void expandArray(int ***grades,int oldSize,int newSize)
{
    grades = realloc(grades, newSize*sizeof(int*));
    // ...
}
```

*Note:* But 3D pointers is usually not a good practice : you might want to modify `expandArray` so it returns a new `int**`.

Comment: when i do `grades = realloc(grades, newSize*sizeof(int));` inside the main it works but when i move the same thing to the function it doesnt do i need to send `int ***grades` to the function?

Comment: You need to send the address of `int ** grades` : `expandArray(&grades,oldClasses,classes);` (I had a typo in my answer : I updated the signature of `expandArray`)

Comment: ok i think i get it now. the adress of `int** grades` is of type `int***` thats why we use `int***` in the function.Everything now works fine if i take `fillArray(grades,oldSize,newSize);` out of the function and call it in the main.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check for value of `classes` inside `main()`

When you get number of classed the second time you are reallocating memory within the function `expandArray()` and this expansion is not visible outside of that function so when you are freeing you might try to free some unallocated memory hence the crash.